# Send message to Whatsapp/Tango/Kik/Viber via Email

Tags: c#, android, ios, email

I was researching on how to send text via email and found ways like for Verizon numbers you'll need to send the email to "10DIGITNUMBER"@vtext.com however you can't send images I think so I'd like to send it on Whatsapp/Viber/Tango/Kik or any Android/iOS application that is able to receive texts/images, so I'm trying to find ways to send message or images to these apps via emails, I'll also be fine If there's something else that will work.

Basically I'm working on a C# tracking project, it'll take a screenshots of the desktop and then it'll send it to anyone via email and they'll receive it on their mobile with alerts to see if everything is working fine, like every hour or every 2 - 3 hours.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541573/whats-app-api-in-net-cant-send-images

Look at their code... Maybe it helps?

Comment: even  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609694/how-to-send-image-audio-or-video-through-the-whatsapp-api-php