# How to send image,audio or video through the WhatsApp API - PHP

Tags: php, whatsapp

> I have Implemented an WhatsAPI - PHP on my site, but am only able to
>   send messages but not the Media files like Images, Audio or Video.

I got the WhatsApp API for PHP

[image]

This is my screen.

I am not getting how to send an image or any other media files through this API.
I have tried all url for image sending like.

- http://www.sample.com/images/sample.jpg
- C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\sample.jpg

But it still not able to send any media file. 
Please let me know how to send an image from this API. What am doing wrong....?

Comment: have you got solution to this issue?

Comment: Not yet... am waiting for answer.... Its now pending project... am trying myself also... if i get anything, will comment here... :)

Comment: @BaraskarSandeep hey friend please can you provide above example whatever you have implemented,thanks in advance !

Comment: Hello Sandeep, Could you please send me code? I badly need it to integrate it in one of my project. Thank you

Comment: hey did you fine any solution for this ? actually i was looking for a sharing option of watsapp on my website.

Answer (score 0):

as i read the example functions in the API files you will see this,

```
//send picture
$w->sendMessageImage($target, "demo/x3.jpg");
```

and of this code you may need to pass the image absolute url to the api

since you are working on localhost, you may not success sending the image, you may need to try it on real server.

and the image should be on same server **NOT** external image url

Answer (score -1):

I Hope this also will work. Please try and let us know the result.

`while($w->pollMessage()); after $w->sendMessageImage($target, "demo/x3.jpg");`