# Whats App Api in .net Cant send Images

Tags: c#, api, whatsapp

I am not getting how to send image to any number using WhatsApiNet I tried writing like D:/img.jpg in COnsole window but its sending the path as a text
This Error I am getting while using this code

```
case "/image":
byte[] imgData = File.ReadAllBytes(@"d:\My Creations\DSC_0423 copy.jpg");
wa.SendMessageImage(tmpUser.GetFullJid(), imgData, ApiBase.ImageType.JPEG);
break;!
```

Comment: When I try this code I only get the following exception:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'd:\My Creations\DSC_0423 copy.jpg'. This is because the image isn't there. When using an existing image (or file), it works fine.

Can you be more specific about the error you get?

Comment: Ok i got it and i solved it

Comment: Problem is to turn off receiver as soon as i comment the receiver it starts working